# How to best handle variable item count (and order) when selecting from unordered list

Tags: javascript, node.js, queryselector

I get innerText-Properties from list-items inside a ul-element that can have anything from 4 up to 10 li-items.
Some items like profilname, age and location will always be there, others like current term, prior degree and other information about a student profile can be filled, but don't have to.
So the list will have a different length for almost every profile and the :nth-child(x) - Element
will contain different information all the time.
I want to feed a object constructor with that data, that expects say the degree as the 5th argument.

How would you go about checking which information is present in the list and setting a placeholder like "n.a." for missing values? Is that something I should even try doing inside my node-script? Or is that a job for later in the database?

My puppeteer function to get the elements via their querySelectors up to that problem looks like this:

```
var ratingDetails = await page.evaluate(() => {

//get each element (that could be available) from a div

   let text = document.querySelector("div.report-text").innerText
   let age = document.querySelector
             ("div.card-block > ul.list-unstyled > li:nth-child(1) > span").innerText
   let sex = document.querySelector
             ("div.card-block > ul.list-unstyled > li:nth-child(2) > span").innerText      
   let startYear = document.querySelector
             ("div.card-block > ul.list-unstyled > li:nth-child(3) > span").innerText
   let studyForm = document.querySelector
             ("div.card-block > ul.list-unstyled > li:nth-child(4) > span").innerText
   let location = document.querySelector
             ("div.card-block > ul.list-unstyled > li:nth-child(5) > span").innerText
          
     [...and some more...]

    })
    
//and then use the spread syntax to fill my constructor

await ratingDetails.map(facts => new ReportObject(...facts)));
```

Many thanks for any advice how to handle that issue!

Comment: The first thing that would need to be clarified is `So the list will have a different length for almost every profile and the :nth-child(x) - Element will contain different information all the time.`. I take that as element 1 won't always be age, element 2 won't always be sex etc.. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, correct! If somebody doesn't provide his age - which would be the first if that field is filled - then some other info would be the first li-element.

Comment: Do you have control over the generating of the list items? Does each list item at least have an indicator of what the data is? For example for Age, does it actually say: `Age: 30 ` or just `30`?

Comment: I have no control over the generation of the list. I'm scraping a website (terms of use and robots.txt checked - it's www.studycheck.de). It does say "age:" inside the li-element and than the actual value is inside a span-element with a class .value attached.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a lot of try and error I came up with the following solution:

1. loop over every li-element in the unordert list und grab the innerText-Properties

```
let text = [];
for (let counter = 1; counter <= metaListe; counter++) {
  text = await page.evaluate((counter) => {
  let liElements = document.querySelector(`div.card-block > ul.list-unstyled > li:nth-child(${counter})`).innerText.trim();
  return liElements;
  }, counter);
```

2. define some regEx-Patterns for all possible li-items

```
const patt_jahrStudBeginn = /^Studienbeginn/;
      const patt_abschluss = /^Abschluss/i;
      const patt_aktFS = /^Aktuelles/;
      const patt_studienForm = /^Studienform/;
      [and some more...]
```

3. compare the innerText-Properties from step 1 with the patterns and return a variable if it's a match (and continue with the next string/innerText

```
if(!document.querySelector(`div.card-block > ul.list-unstyled > li:nth-child(${counter})`))
    {return;}
    else{
      if(patt_studienForm.test(text)) {
        let studForm = document.querySelector(`div.card-block > ul.list-unstyled > li:nth-child(${counter}) > span`).innerText;
      }else{
        if(patt_studienDauer.test(text)) {
          let studDauer = document.querySelector(`div.card-block > ul.list-unstyled > li:nth-child(${counter}) > span`).innerText;
        }else{
          if(patt_jahrStudBeginn.test(text)) {
            let jahrBeginn = document.querySelector(`div.card-block > ul.list-unstyled > li:nth-child(${counter}) > span`).innerText;
          }else{
            if(patt_aktFS.test(text)) {
              let aktFS = document.querySelector(`div.card-block > ul.list-unstyled > li:nth-child(${counter}) > span`).innerText;
[...and more...]
```

And return all variables containing the different information from the page.evaluate()-function.
It took me quite some time to understand, that I have to pass any counting variable to the .evaluate()-method to be able to use the current loop index inside it to refer to the n-th list element.

That super deep if-condition can't be good code. I will probally ask how to enhance that type of comparison with an array in a separate question. But it works as it is.